# invoking lambda function gives "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'semver'"

Tags: aws-lambda, yarnpkg, semantic-versioning

I'm working on a lambda function and when I try to invoke it I get the following error

```
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'semver'".
```

details

```
Unable to import module 'dist/index': Error
```

If I add semver to package.json then it works fine.  This started happening suddenly.  A bit of background information, I'm using a monorepo with yarn and lerna.

Comment: are you including your `node_modules` folder when you zip and upload your code?

Comment: yes I am.  Plus this was working yesterday, suddenly it stopped working.